# ASP.NET 4 HttpHandler in Custom Route

Tags: routes, httphandler, asp.net-4.0

I have made a custom Route which override GetRouteData. How can I know what type of request is being done? Everything passes the GetRoutData function (.css, .js, .axd, etc) and I would like to do something only if it is a System.Web.UI.Page.

But httpContext.Request.CurrentHandler is always null because the routing takes place just before the handler mapping...

Answer (score 0):

any reason you can't limit your route to .aspx files?
Do you not want to handle pages that superclass ui.page?